# Program does not contain a static 'main' method suitable for an entry point : i have tries even removing access modifier before static

Tags: c#

```
using System;

namespace inheritance1
{
    public class Employee
    {
        public string FirstName;
        public string LastName;
        public string Email;

        public void PrintFullName()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(FirstName + " " + LastName);
        }

    }
    public class FullTimeEmployee : Employee
    {
        public float YearlySalary;
    }
    public class PartTimeEmployee : Employee
    {
        public float HourlyRate;
    }
    public class Program
    {
       public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            FullTimeEmployee FTE = new FullTimeEmployee();
            FTE.FirstName = "Max";
            FTE.LastName = "Striker";
            FTE.YearlySalary = 500000;
            FTE.PrintFullName();

            PartTimeEmployee PTE = new PartTimeEmployee();
            PTE.FirstName = "king";
            PTE.LastName = "Maker";
            PTE.HourlyRate = 500;
            PTE.PrintFullName();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Habib's answer has it.  Interesting though, the project template should have setup everything properly for you...are you using VS?

Comment: @rory.ap I doubt this was from a template!

Comment: it doesn't look like he used any of the templates actually. EDIT: @DavidG Ninja lol

Comment: yes  i am using visual studio

Comment: For what it's worth, the convention in C# is all methods should have Pascal casing.

Comment: "yes i am using visual studio" then what happened to your project template?  Why are you writing this from scratch when the template does it all for you>?

Comment: i tried from scratch to give it a shot first i written it on notepad and then moved entire code to vs

Answer (score 8):

It is `Main` with an upper case `M`, not `main`.

```
public static void Main(String[] args)
{
```

[Main () and Other Methods (C# vs Java)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228506(v=vs.90).aspx)

> Every C# application must contain a single Main method specifying
>   where program execution is to begin. In C#, **Main is capitalized**,
>   while Java uses lowercase main.